# Email de confirmação de cadastro

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, envio-de-email

Eu fiz um cadastro com cpf e email. Já coloquei pra validar o cpf e tal, e consigo enviar o email para o usuário que colocou o email lá, mas eu preciso que o cadastro só seja feito se o email realmente existir. No caso, eu teria que fazer um email único de confirmação de cadastro pra quando ele clicar lá, validar o cadastro, ou teria alguma forma mais fácil? Pq quando eu envio o email para algum nao existente, ele confirma mesmo assim o cadastro e é colocado no bd. E como faço isso?

O código de enviar email:

```
    <?php

    require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->Host = 'host aqui';
   $mail->Port = 587;
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->Username = 'emailr';
   $mail->Password = 'senha';

   $mail->SMTPSecure = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl
   $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl

   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Mostra os bugs


    //E-mail remetente (deve ser igual ao que esta enviando)
    $mail->From = 'email';

    //Nome do remetente
    $mail->FromName ='Lojas';

    //Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Subject = 'Texto';

    //Corpo da mensagem
    $mail->Body = 'Ola';

    //Corpo da mensagem em texto
    $mail->AltBody = 'Conteudo do e-mail em texto';

    //Destinatario 
    $mail->AddAddress ('exemplo@email');

    if ($mail->Send()) {
        echo "e-mail enviado com sucesso";
       echo'<script> alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!")</script>';
    }else{
        echo "Erro no envio do e-mail" .$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

?>
```

Código de cadastro:

```
                    <label >CPF*:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" title="Digite o CPF no formato nnn.nnn.nnn-nn" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="000.000.000-00" maxlength="14" required /><span id="resposta"></span>

  <br>
                    <label inputemail>E-mail*:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg email" placeholder="SeuEmail@Email.com" maxlength="50" required />

                      <br>
  <br>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" disbled/ >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        <span id="cpf"></span>Cadastrar</button>
```

Tela de validaCadastro:

```
<?php
// ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);

?>
<?php

require_once "config/conexao.php";

  $var1 = $_POST['cpf'];
  $var2 = $_POST['email'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '$var2'";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cpf = '$var1'";


      $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
          echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro existente.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
        }

        $var1 = $_POST['cpf'];
        $var2 = $_POST['email'];



            if ($mail->Send()) {
                echo "e-mail enviado com sucesso";
               echo'<script> alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!")</script>';

            if(!$stmt){
              echo 'erro na consulta: '. $conn->error .' - '. $conn->error;
            }



            }else{
                echo "Erro no envio do e-mail" .$mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
```

Comment: O cadastro deve existir de qualquer forma, o e-mail de confirmação é só para confirmar. O que você pode fazer é só liberar o acesso após o e-mail estiver confirmado.

Comment: Então...eu coloco um email que não existe, e mesmo assim o cadastro é efetuado com sucesso. E eu sei que o email nao existe pq já verifiquei isso

Comment: é só cpf e email?

Comment: Sim. Coloquei cpf como sendo PK, e validei o cpf pra ver se existe ou não. Agora tenho que validar o email, saber se ele existe mesmo ou não

Comment: Penso em duas soluções: primeira enviar para o email de cadastro ->>  `Clique <a href='http://dominio.com/ativar.php?cpf=".$cpf."&email=".$email."'>aqui</a> para ativar seu cadastro.` Dai vc pega esses valores e faz insert no banco

Comment: Mas como faço exatamente isso? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade? Enviar o e-mail para o usuario com essa linha?

Comment: Eu consigo enviar email para o cliente, o que eu nao sei é enviar um email com link de confirmação, para caso ele receba o email, tenha que clicar no link, aí quando clicar o email vai pro bd

Comment: tem que colocar exatamente essa linha no corpo da mensagem do email

Comment: Não aconselharia enviar o CPF no link de validação. Já que é um dado sigiloso, seria melhor ter no banco uma coluna com um código único para cada usuário de uns 8 caracteres (letras e números), daí cria o link de validação usando esse código + email.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim, mas como faço isso exatamente?

Comment: @ÐvÐ, no conteúdo da mensagem nao vai mostrar nenhum dado de cpf

Comment: @ÐvÐ trabalho extra para limpar banco com não retornados, se não quer expor cpf em link faça uso de localStorage que seria a segunda solução

Comment: Coloca o seu código que envia email na pergunta

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo pronto

Comment: Se alguma resposta solucionou sua pergunta, não deixe de marcá-la como aceita, veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Esquematização de validação de cadastro através de um *link de validação*

Recomendaria ter na tabela de *cadastro de usuários* uma coluna de código único para cada usuário, de no mínimo 8 caracteres (letras e números). Esse código deve ser gerado randomicamente por algum gerador de código ou você pode pegar a data atual (ano, mês, dia, hora, minutos e segundos, ficando mais ou menos assim: `20171204134422`). Caso não queira isso, você pode usar o `id` do usuário no banco mesmo, se não houver problema dele saber esta informação.

**1º.** O usuário se cadastra no site. O cadastro fica inativo e é enviado um email de confirmação com o link para validar o cadastro. O link seria algo assim:

http://nome_do_site.com.br/validar.php?email=fuladodetal@gmail.com&codigo=sh35j87k

Exemplo de como ficaria a mensagem enviada ao usuário:

> Olá! Bem-vindo ao site!
>
> Clique no link a seguir para confirmar seu cadastro:
>   http://nome_do_site.com.br/validar.php?email=fuladodetal@gmail.com&codigo=sh35j87k

O código do corpo da mensagem você montaria desta forma:

```
<?php
$corpo = '
Olá! Bem-vindo ao site!
<br /><br />
Clique no link a seguir para confirmar seu cadastro:
<br />
<a href="http://nome_do_site.com.br/validar.php?email='.$email_usuario.'&codigo='.$codigo.'" target="_blank">http://nome_do_site.com.br/validar.php?email='.$email_usuario.'&codigo='.$codigo.'</a>
';

$mail->Body = $corpo;
?>
```

**2º.** Crie um arquivo no seu site `validar.php` (exemplo) para receber e tratar o `email` e o `codigo` recebidos no link, verificando se os dois coincidem no mesmo cadastro, validando se existirem ou não validando caso haja alguma divergência.

Este é apenas um exemplo bem simples só para ilustrar o processo.

Em relação á programação de todo o processo (inclusão do cadastro no banco, validação e ativação) são outras questões, e caso você não tenha conhecimento para fazê-los, pode pesquisar no site e encontrar como fazer.

Comment: vixi, não gostaram da sua resposta e nem comentaram, porque será que não comentam?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Não tem problema. Inclusive tentei dar uma melhorada. Eu dei o caminho das pedras, a programação o AP deve pelo menos saber.

Comment: Não nada de errado com a sua resposta, aliás acho que a sua solução é o caminho certo a seguir. Só não percebo essas pessoas que colocam um "-" e nem deixam comentários para se perceber o que está de errado.

Comment: @lazyFox Pois eh. O -1 seria pra quando a resposta não é útil. No caso, acho que a minha resposta seja útil, só não dá de bandeja todo sistema funcionando.

Comment: Creio que é um boa resposta técnica, explicando o passo a passo, não posso afirmar que vai resolver o problema da AP, mas eu pessoalmente acho ela a mais ideal, ainda mais que se preocupa com a segurança no momento da confirmação, ainda sim como sugestão, o código randômico poderia ser uma hash um pouco mais complicada, datas, horas e afins podem não ser um método garantido. +1 por indicar principalmente a preocupação com a segurança.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar inserir no banco um email que não existe e futuramente ter que excluir, pode fazer desse modo.

Comentários no código

Formulário e Envio de email na mesma página

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cpf']) && isset($_POST['email'])){     
    require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->Host = 'host aqui';
   $mail->Port = 587;
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->Username = 'emailr';
   $mail->Password = 'senha';

   $mail->SMTPSecure = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl
   $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl

   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Mostra os bugs

   //recupera via post valor do cpf
   $cpf = Trim(str_replace("'","",$_POST["cpf"]));
   //cookie cujo valor é o cpf com duração de 2 dias
   setcookie("cpf",$cpf,time()+(2*86400),"/");

   //email para usar no corpo da mensagem e em Destinatario
   $e_mail = $_POST["email"];
   $e_mail = Trim(str_replace("'","",$e_mail));


    //E-mail remetente (deve ser igual ao que esta enviando)
    $mail->From = 'email';

    //Nome do remetente
    $mail->FromName ='Lojas';

    //Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Subject = 'Texto';

    //Corpo da mensagem
    $mail->Body = "Ola, Clique <a href='http://dominio.com/validaCadastro.php?mail=".$e_mail."'>aqui</a> para ativar seu cadastro.";

    //Corpo da mensagem em texto
    $mail->AltBody = 'Conteudo do e-mail em texto';


    //Destinatario 
    $mail->AddAddress ($e_mail);

    if ($mail->Send()) {
        echo "e-mail enviado com sucesso";
       echo'<script> alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!")</script>';
    }else{
        echo "Erro no envio do e-mail" .$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>

<form class="form" id="form1" method="POST" action="">

<label >CPF*:</label>
<input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" title="Digite o CPF no formato nnn.nnn.nnn-nn" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="000.000.000-00" maxlength="14" required /><span id="resposta"></span>
<br>
 <label inputemail>E-mail*:</label>
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg email" placeholder="SeuEmail@Email.com" maxlength="50" required />

<br>
<br>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" disbled/ >
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
 <span id="cpf"></span>Cadastrar</button>

 </form>
```

Pagina que insere no banco de dados `validaCadastro.php`

```
if ($_GET["mail"] != "") {

 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

 //recupera valor do cookie
 $cpf = $_COOKIE['cpf'];
 $getMail= $_GET["mail"];

 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE email = '$getMail'");

        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        if ($row[0] > 0) {
             $alerta =("E-mail (".$getMail.") já existente.");
        } else {
            $mysqli->query("Insert into tabela (email,cpf) values ('".$getMail."','".$cpf."')");
        }


}
```

**Considerando os comentários de `Guilherme Nascimento`:**

> "Não creio que cookies seja um bom caminho, da maneira que aplicou pode ser algo que não funcione, ainda mais se o usuário eventualmente não puder confirmar o e-mail na mesma máquina que se cadastrou, fora que dependendo se o validaCadastro.php?mail=".$e_mail."' fizer o autologon poderá ser uma grande brecha de segurança,"

**a melhor solução é a da resposta do ÐvÐ!**

Comment: Nao entendi muito bem seu código. Esses dados de email e cpf terão que ser pegos pela página cadastro, certo? Vou atualizar os códigos na pergunta

Comment: sim, a pagina cadastro submete o formulário para a pagina do email

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada nos códigos que coloquei agora? Então...o validaCadastro vai ser trocado pelo ativar.php?

Comment: Exatamente o validaCadastro vai ser trocado pelo ativar.php,  O cadastro envia para a pagina do envio de email (que pode ser a mesma pagina). A pagina ativar (quando o usuario clicar no link recebido) verifica se já existe o email no banco, se não existir insere

Comment: Mas não é isso que eu quero. Eu preciso verificar se o email realmente existe de verdade, no gmail, outlook etc.

Comment: Você só vai saber se o email realmente existe se o usuário der retorno, fora isso vc deveria ter uma tabela com todos os emails validos do mundo inteiro para vc fazer o teste, ora pois pois!!

Comment: Acho que entendi... mas fica dando erro de sintaxe em:
`$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE email = '$_GET["mail"]'");`

Comment: @NazareLisboa, desatenção minha, corrigi e editei a resposta.

Comment: O email é enviado pra mim e tal, mas ele da esse erro: Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\testaOficial\ativar.php on line 3
Nessa linha de código: `if ($_GET["mail"] != "")`

Comment: E fica dando erro do cpf, como se nao tivesse encontrado: Undefined index: cpf in ...

Comment: Continua dizendo a mesma coisa, e quando eu clico no link que veio pro meu email, mostra isso: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs...

Comment: Beleza. Aguardo

Comment: na pagina do formulario mude para `if(isset($_POST['cpf']) && isset($_POST['email'])){  ` Fiz teste e deu certo no meu server

Comment: Agora quando clico no link que foi enviado pro meu email, recebo esse erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\validaCadastro.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\validaCadastro.php on line 12

Comment: Apenas citando os pontos que acho problemáticos na resposta: Não creio que cookies seja um bom caminho, da maneira que aplicou pode ser algo que não funcione, ainda mais se o usuário eventualmente não puder confirmar o e-mail na mesma máquina que se cadastrou, fora que dependendo se o `validaCadastro.php?mail=".$e_mail."'` fizer o autologon poderá ser uma grande brecha de segurança, a resposta do ÐvÐ sugere um código de validação, o que penso que poderia ser uma ideia para você implementar no seu código. (cc @NazareLisboa)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, pelo que entendi ela não quer inserir no banco email não existentes `Então...eu coloco um email que não existe, e mesmo assim o cadastro é efetuado com sucesso.` No entanto, ativar cadastro é outra situação não aventada na pergunta.